# Deleting AD snapshots older than 30 days with NTDSUTIL

Tags: batch-file, active-directory, windows-server-2008, snapshot

My domain controller is running Windows Server 2008.

I have been able to script AD snapshot creation using the following batch commands in conjunction with Task Scheduler.

```
@echo off
ntdsutil snapshot "activate instance ntds" create quit quit
exit
```

Now I want to use a batch file to remove AD snapshots older than 30 days.  There is a delete command within ntdsutil but I'm having trouble putting the delete operation into a for loop.  Is there a way to gain access to the index variable that "delete" references?

I want to:

1. Open ntdsutil and enter the snapshot context
2. Run delete %s in a loop where %s is greater than 60
3. Exit the loop and ntdsutil

Here is a screenshot of the ntds snapshot command-line screen:

```
ntdsutil: snapshot
snapshot: ?

 ?                             - Show this help information
 Activate Instance %s          - Set "NTDS" or a specific AD LDS instance
                                 as the active instance.
 Create                        - Create a snapshot
 Delete %s                     - Delete snapshot with index or guid %s. Specify
 * to delete all snapshots
 Help                          - Show this help information
 List All                      - List snapshots
 List Mounted                  - List mounted snapshots
 Mount %s                      - Mount snapshot with index or guid %s
 Quit                          - Return to the prior menu
 Unmount %s                    - Unmount snapshot with index or guid %s. Specify
 * to unmount all mounted snapshots

snapshot: list all
 1: 2014/02/06:15:58 {052e85ae-7379-4164-8b7c-1be14fea1754}
 2:   C: {bdfe5953-3d4f-4195-b94b-593f66c2bc1e}

 3: 2014/02/07:07:12 {82daa70b-ac7e-438c-80f5-78de8a4500f7}
 4:   C: {0a05a0ab-4faa-442f-a65a-88579c037e1a}

 5: 2014/02/07:07:27 {e761dded-b13c-4fac-b050-5b9d042cec73}
 6:   C: {2af92c27-765c-43e8-a384-1bf41b0634b9}

snapshot: delete 5
Snapshot {2af92c27-765c-43e8-a384-1bf41b0634b9} deleted.
snapshot: list all
 1: 2014/02/06:15:58 {052e85ae-7379-4164-8b7c-1be14fea1754}
 2:   C: {bdfe5953-3d4f-4195-b94b-593f66c2bc1e}

 3: 2014/02/07:07:12 {82daa70b-ac7e-438c-80f5-78de8a4500f7}
 4:   C: {0a05a0ab-4faa-442f-a65a-88579c037e1a}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a batch code i have made. He is based on text files to manage retention of the Snapshots.

Enjoy.

```
@echo off

REM +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
REM ¦   Autor       : Ficzko                                                                                            ¦
REM ¦   Version     : 1.0                                                                                               ¦
REM ¦   Date        : 2014/10/22                                                                                        ¦
REM ¦   Comments    : Batch File for manage retention of the Snapshots into NTDSUTIL.                                   ¦
REM ¦                 Each Snapshot create a txt file. The txt file containt the id of the backup.                      ¦ 
REM +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

REM     Logs Location (Used for manage retention). The folder have to contain only the text files of this batch.
set mypath=C:\ADSnapLogs\
if not exist %mypath% mkdir %mypath%

REM     Setup of the retention of snapshots in seconds  (1 Day = 86400, 31 Days = 2678400, ...)
set myretention=2678400

REM     Generation of a Linux TimeStamp for the naming of log files 
REM     (Time in seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00  ex : 205329600 for Sun Jul 4 12:00:00 1976 GMT)
for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_utctime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (set %%x)
set /a z=(14-100%Month%%%100)/12, y=10000%Year%%%10000-z
set /a mydate=y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400+(153*(100%Month%%%100+12*z-3)+2)/5+Day-719469
set /a mydate=mydate*86400+100%Hour%%%100*3600+100%Minute%%%100*60+100%Second%%%100

REM     Creation of the snapshot
echo Snapshot in progress
ntdsutil snapshot "activate instance ntds" create quit quit > %mypath%%mydate%.txt

REM     Get the ID of the Snapshot and save it into the log file
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims= " %%a in ('findstr /i /c:"{" "%mypath%%mydate%.txt"') do @echo %%c > %mypath%%mydate%.txt

REM     Removing old snapshot
echo Removing old snapshot
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in ('dir %mypath% /b') do call :CalcRetension %%a
goto end
:CalcRetension
set val=%1
set /a result=%mydate%-%myretention%
IF %val% LSS %result% (
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%a in ('findstr /i /c:"{" "%mypath%%val%.txt"') do call :removeSnapshot %%a %val%
)
goto end
:removeSnapshot
set guid=%1
set filename=%2
ntdsutil snapshot "delete %guid%" quit quit
del /S "%mypath%%filename%.txt"
goto end
:End
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing daily snapshots with the same script and I have 5 latest snapshots all the time. I'm not bothering cleaning them up.